# how to run a script in GCP machine using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

i have a script file named as auto.sh in my local laptop and i want to run this script file in GCP machine as soon as provision
i created this terraform file

```
resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "default3" {
  disk     = google_compute_disk.default2.id
  instance = google_compute_instance.default.id
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "test"
  machine_type = "custom-8-16384"
  zone         = "us-central1-a"

  tags = ["foo", "bar"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "centos-cloud/centos-7"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config {
      
    }
  }
  metadata_startup_script = "touch abcd.txt" 

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [attached_disk]
  }
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "default2" {
  name  = "test-disk"
  type  = "pd-balanced"
  zone  = "us-central1-a"
  image = "centos-7-v20210609"
  size =  100
}
```

and this is working fine now i want to run that script

Answer (score 3):

You should replace the

```
metadata_startup_script = "touch abcd.txt"
```

with either you script inline if it's short enough, or with something like

```
metadata_startup_script = "${file("/path/to/your/file")}"
```

To load it from a file

See [metadata_startup_script docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#metadata_startup_script)

Comment: i just replace to this metadata_startup_script = "${file("C:/Users/Rohan/Desktop/new/autoo.sh")}" and inside my autoo.sh containing a command that is touch abc.txt but still it is not created